# Why does C not have pass by address/reference without pointers?

Tags: c++, c, memory-efficient

Consider the trivial test of this swap function in C++ which uses pass by pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void swap_ints(int *a, int *b)
{
   int temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
   return;
}

int main(void)
{
   int a = 1;
   int b = 0;
   cout << "a = " << a << "\t" << "b = " << b << "\n\n";
   swap_ints(&a, &b);
   cout << "a = " << a << "\t" << "b = " << b << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Does this program use more memory than if I had passed by address? Such as in this function decleration:

```
void swap_ints(int &a, int &b)
{
   int temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
   return;
}
```

Does this pass-by-reference version of the C++ function use less memory, by not needing to create the pointer variables?

And does C not have this "pass-by-reference" ability the same that C++ does? If so, then why not, because it means more memory efficient code right? If not, what is the pitfall behind this that C does not adopt this ability. I suppose what I am not consider is the fact that C++ probably creates pointers to achieve this functionality behind the scenes. Is this what the compiler actually does -- and so C++ really does not have any true advantage besides neater code?

Comment: References **are** pointers, they just *look* different. Nothing is different about them underneath, though. (Except that they can't be null.)

Comment: @Mehrdad So then my assumption was correct, there is no functionality except to make the code more neat.

Comment: Not just neat, but safer too, because a reference cannot be NULL like a pointer can. But under the hood, references and pointers usually produce the same machine code when compiled.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-nPlease check out between 6.34 - 8.51 . It has been adviced that we shouldn't think references like pointers .

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir I think your link is too long/was broken

Comment: "References can't be null" is a fallacy. What it really means is that, formally, the undefined behavior when you "pass a null reference" is invoked at the function call rather than at some point inside the function, but either way it's a matter of violating the interface contract in a way that ultimately results in undefined behavior. In terms of implementation (the generated machine code), the *exact same thing* happens whether it's a pointer or a reference.

Comment: sorry....                                        http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n                               Also I think passing arguments by reference may not be a good idea for arrays and that could be one possible reason why it is not indicated like that by standart ofcourse we can't know what compiler does  .

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir at 6:21 he says "because of ..." what exactly did he say? I thought he said "constants" but I can readily take the address of a constant. Sometimes I have trouble understanding people speak though, what did he say, because of what?

Comment: The part about references  which I wanted to underline is between at 6:34 - 8:51 .                                                       I think 6:21 he is talking about what is right value and what is left value . I don't believe you can take the adress of right values(he is not talking about const variables).

Comment: This is a matter of personal opinion, but although pass-by-reference is very convenient, in some ways I prefer C's pointers-only approach. Having to explicitly pass in a pointer when you call the function, and explicitly dereference it in the function body, effectively prevents you from forgetting that you are passing a variable by reference (whereupon it may be modified), and similarly prevents you from unwittingly writing code in your function that modifies something when you didn't intend to. Although the latter can be prevented by adding a `const` modifier to the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to be sure would be to examine the code the compiler generated for each and compare the two to see what you get.

That said, I'd be a bit surprised to see a real difference (at least when optimization was enabled), at least for a reasonably mainstream compiler. You *might* see a difference for a compiler on some really tiny embedded system that hasn't been updated in the last decade or so, but even there it's honestly pretty unlikely.

I should also add that in most cases I'd expect to see code for such a trivial function generated inline, so there was on function call or parameter passing involved at all. In a typical case, it's likely to come down to nothing more than a couple of loads and stores.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse counting variables in your code with counting memory used by the processor.  C++ has many abstractions that hide the inner workings of the compiler in order to make things simpler and easier for a human to follow.

By design, C does not have quite as many levels of abstractions as C++.